# Definition of positive measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

[image]

Why Rudin assumes that $\mu(A)<\infty$ for at least one $A\in \mathfrak{M}$?
What about if $\mu(A)=\infty$ for any $A\in\mathfrak{M}$?

Comment: Not a very interesting measure, is it?

Comment: A measure that is $\infty$ everywhere has no useful application. Also, we could like to have $\mu  \emptyset = 0$.

Comment: @copper.hat, Sorry but I still don't understand why Rudin does not consider "always infinite" measure?

Comment: It is useful to have $\mu \emptyset = 0$, otherwise the measure of all sets must be $\infty$, and such a measure has no real utility. It is a bit like dealing with the linear space $\{0\}$.

Comment: But Rudin prove $\mu \varnothing =0$ in the following theorem.

Comment: That is because he has assumed that there is at least one $A$ for which $\mu A < \infty$. Hence $\mu \emptyset = \mu (A \cup \emptyset) - \mu A = 0$. The measure that is inifinite on all non empty sets is a valid (but also fairly trivial) measure.

Comment: @copper.hat, Why always infinite measure is not useful?

Comment: Well, it is hard to give a useful demonstration of uselessness :-).

Comment: @copper.hat, Good answer :)

Comment: @carmichael561, Why it's not intersting measure?

Comment: $\infty$ is a concept introduced more for convenience. Essentially it means "undefined" and you can very well have a measure theory without it, but introducing it simplifies our expressions. Think about why you can't integrate a function valuing both $-\infty$ and $\infty$ on sets of strictly positive measure. If your measure is undefined for all measurable sets, then it doesn't sound interesting to me.

Comment: @QiyuWen This is deeply wrong, $\infty$ is **not** introduced for convenience in measure theory and certainly does not mean "undefined". The Lebesgue measure of $(0,+\infty)$ is well defined and one wants it to be $+\infty$. The fact that, on the contrary, $\infty-\infty$ is undefined is another matter entirely.

Comment: Mathematicians often reject trivial cases out of habit and tradition -- sometimes even when doing so is actively harmful. I do not know if that is the case here or if there is a good reason for doing so.

Comment: @Hurkyl Old Walter says so explicitely: this is to avoid trivialities (a very good reason, if you ask me).

Comment: @Did: Avoiding trivialities is not an inherently good thing. Yes, sometimes, avoiding trivialities means you get rid of a lot of little details. But sometimes, avoiding trivialities means that you save yourself a trivial amount of trouble at the cost of making a lot of things more complicated.

Comment: @Hurkyl A hint to know the correct option in the present case: Lebesgue theory is approx. 100 years old.

Comment: @Did, What trivialities we get if we suppose that our measure is always infinite?

Comment: That the additivity $\mu(A\cup B)=\mu(A)+\mu(B)$ for every disjoint measurable sets $A$ and $B$, while still true, becomes not hugely informative, say. Recall that measures are used to, well... *measure* sets, hence to declare that everything is very-very-big, albeit a legal way of measuring things, is not a very useful one.

Comment: Well it must be said that the measure that is $0$ on all sets in $\mathcal M$ is a very useful concept.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $\mu (A)=\infty $ for all $A $, then $\mu $ doesn't distinguish between sets at all. You would have $\int f=\infty $ for all $f\geq0$ that are nonzero on at least one point, and you cannot even define the integral of any function that changes signs. So basically you get no measure theory whatsoever.

Comment: Dear Martin! Why we can't define the integral of function which changes sign?

Comment: In measure theory there are conventions (axioms in a sense) for how $\infty$ behaves under the usual algebraic operations. For instance $\infty + \infty = \infty$, however the form $\infty - \infty$ is not defined in anyway since it leads to inconsistencies. If we integrated over a measure where every set has measure $\infty$ then we would be constantly faced with problem just stated, since we traditionally split the integral of a function that is not necessarily positive into its integral over the negative and positive parts.

Comment: This is not convincing; it tries to answer the question of why such measure would be uninteresting, not why the very definition of measure should be modified to exclude it.

Comment: @Hurkyl, Sorry. Do you adress this comment to me?

Comment: @RFZ: No: it was directed at Martin

Comment: @Hurkyl, Do you know why in definition of measure says that exists al least on set $A$  from sigma-algebra $\mathfrak{M}$ such $\mu(A)<\infty$? This seems to me very weird. Maybe you have some idea?!

Comment: This answer is unconvincing for a second reason, since it would also apply to the measure with $\mu(A) = \infty$ for every *nonempty* $A$, which *is* allowed.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of measure you quote doesn't give the full form of countable additivity, which would apply to a disjoint collection of cardinality *zero* the same as any finite or countably infinite cardinality.

Since an empty union is the empty set and an empty sum is zero, the full version of additivity would imply $\mu(\varnothing) = 0$.

The hypothesis that $\mu(\varnothing) = 0$ is equivalent (given additivity over countably infinite disjoint unions) to the hypothesis that there is at least one measurable set of finite measure.

Consequently, IMO, the *intent* is to have the full version of countable additivity while only giving a simplified statement of that property.

Comment: Note that many resources and book includes above definition like mine and requires that exists at least one set which measure is finite.

Comment: @RFZ: I would chalk the alternate presentation up to tradition. It happens in other places too -- e.g. "group homomorphism" is often defined as "preserves the group operation" rather than "preserves the group operation, inversion, and identity".

Comment: ... or just not wanting to talk about empty unions and empty sums.