# Measure positive iff all nonnegative continuous function has positive integral

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, optimization

I was watching [a lecture on polynomial optimization](https://sites.google.com/site/cedricjosz/home/introduction-to-polynomial-optimization), and the speaker mentioned that:

> For compact set $K \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, and $\mu$ be a finite Borel measure. $\mu \geq 0$ means that for all $\phi \in C(K,\mathbb{R})$, it holds that $\forall x \in K, \phi(x) \geq 0 \implies \mu(\phi) = \int \phi \, d\mu \geq 0$. I wonder if this description of a measure being positive is equivalent to the [canonical one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1794954/definition-of-positive-measure), where positive means the measure takes values $[0,+\infty]$

One direction is easy for me. However, I'm not sure how to show that all continuous functions nonnegative integral implies measure being positive.

I tried proving by contradiction, where if $\mu(A) < 0$ for some $A$, we have one continuous function having a negative integral. When $A$ is nice, it's easy to construct a continuous function, for instance set $f(A) = \{ 1 \}$ and $f((A \setminus C)^{\mathsf{c}} ) = \{ 0 \}$, where C can be a set with an arbitrary small measure that "smooth" the border of A. However, I'm not sure if this works for $A$ being some random measurable set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $\mu$ is finite and $K$ is $\sigma$-compact, it follows that $\mu$ is regular. Then Lusin's Theorem applies. So, given measurable $E\subset K$, we have that $1_E=\lim_ng_n$, with $g_n\in C(K)$. In this setting, Lusin's Theorem allows us to choose $g_n$ with $|g_n|\leq1$. Then Dominated Convergence applies, and
$$
\mu(E)=\int_K1_E\,d\mu=\int_K\lim_ng_n\,d\mu=\lim_n\int_Kg_n\,d\mu\geq0. 
$$
In the way they are usually stated, the theorems above do not apply to signed measures. But we can write $\mu=\mu^+-\mu^-$ for positive measures $\mu^\pm$, apply the theorems to each, and combine the results.